# Polynomial paths

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I am studying Vector Spaces and came across the following problem in Artin:

> If $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are quadratic polynomials with real coefficients, show that the image of the path $(x(t), y(t))$ is contained in conic, that is, there is a real quadratic polynomial $f(x,y)$ such that $f(x(t),y(t))$ is identically $0$?

Also, would the answer for the question: for every pair $x(t),y(t)$ of real polynomials satisfies some real polynomial relation $f(x,y)=0$ follow directly from the answer of the above question?

I am not sure where to begin with this problem as I don't understand what they mean by the image of the path. Can anyone please provide some hints?

Comment: Presumably you mean $f(a,b) = 0$ **iff** there exists some $t$ such that $a=x(t), b=y(t)$. (Otherwise $f=0$ would suffice.)

Comment: The image of the path is the set of points $\{ (x(t),y(t)) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | t \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

Comment: @copper.hat: Yes, the degeneracy assumption is implicit here. Also, the fact that the polynomial has to be nonzero will take care of this situation I think.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484490/linearly-dependent-polynomials

Comment: What does he mean by identically 0?

Answer (score 1):

We are looking for a function $F(x,y)$ with the following structure:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}F(x,y)&=&a x^2+b x y+c y^2+d x+e y+f \\
x(t)&=&a_1 t^2+b_1 t+c_1 \\
y(t)&=&a_2 t^2+b_2 t+c_2
\end{array}$$
We want to calculate the unknown coefficients $a,b,c,d,e,f$ of  $F$ such that $$F(x(t),y(t)) \equiv  0$$
This is linear a system of 5 equations. We let [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/)([online calculator](http://maxima-online.org/?inc=r816701650)) do the job

```
(%i2) display2d:false
(%o2) false
(%i3) F(x,y):=a*x^2+b*x*y+c*y^2+d*x+e*y+f
(%o3) F(x,y):=a*x^2+b*x*y+c*y^2+d*x+e*y+f
(%i4) x(t):=a_1*t^2+b_1*t+c_1
(%o4) x(t):=a_1*t^2+b_1*t+c_1
(%i5) y(t):=a_2*t^2+b_2*t+c_2
(%o5) y(t):=a_2*t^2+b_2*t+c_2
(%i6) solve(makelist(coeff(ratexpand(ev(F(x,y),x = x(t),y = y(t))),t,n) = 0,n,0,4),[a,b,c,d,e,f])
(%o6) [[a = (%r6*a_2^2)/a_1^2,b = -(2*%r6*a_2)/a_1,c = %r6,d = (2*%r6*a_1*a_2*c_2-2*%r6*a_2^2*c_1-%r6*a_1*b_2^2+%r6*a_2*b_1*b_2)/a_1^2,
        e = -(2*%r6*a_1^2*c_2-2*%r6*a_1*a_2*c_1-%r6*a_1*b_1*b_2+%r6*a_2*b_1^2)/a_1^2,
        f = (%r6*a_1^2*c_2^2+((-2*%r6*a_1*a_2*c_1)-%r6*a_1*b_1*b_2+%r6*a_2*b_1^2)*c_2+%r6*a_2^2*c_1^2+(%r6*a_1*b_2^2-%r6*a_2*b_1*b_2)*c_1)/a_1^2]]
(%i7) s:solve(append(makelist(coeff(ratexpand(ev(F(x,y),x = x(t),y = y(t))),t,n) = 0,n,0,4),[c = a_1^2]),[a,b,c,d,e,f])
(%o7) [[a = a_2^2,b = -2*a_1*a_2,c = a_1^2,d = 2*a_1*a_2*c_2-2*a_2^2*c_1-a_1*b_2^2+a_2*b_1*b_2,e = (-2*a_1^2*c_2)+2*a_1*a_2*c_1+a_1*b_1*b_2-a_2*b_1^2,
        f = a_1^2*c_2^2+((-2*a_1*a_2*c_1)-a_1*b_1*b_2+a_2*b_1^2)*c_2+a_2^2*c_1^2+(a_1*b_2^2-a_2*b_1*b_2)*c_1]]
(%i8) ratexpand(ev(F(x(t),y(t)),s))
(%o8) 0
```

and get
$$\begin{array}{rcl}a&=&a_2^2,\\
b&=&-2a_1a_2,\\
c&=&a_1^2,\\
d&=&2a_1a_2c_2-2a_2^2c_1-a_1b_2^2+a_2b_1b_2,\\
e&=&
-2a_1^2c_2+2a_1a_2c_1+a_1b_1b_2-a_2b_1^2,\\
f&=&a_1^2c_2^2+(-2a_1a_2c_1-a_1b_1b_2+a_2b_1^2)c_2+a_2^2c_1^2+(a_1b_2^2-a_2b_1b_2)c_1\end{array}$$
There are no assumptions about the coeffizients of $x(t)$ or $y(t)$. But if both $a_1=a_2=0$ then $F \equiv 0$. So if $a_1=a_2=0$ we find another $F$. Set
$$\begin{array}{rcl}F(x,y)&=&d x+e y+f \\
x(t)&=&b_1 t+c_1 \\
y(t)&=&b_2 t+c_2
\end{array}$$

Now  we calculate the unknown coefficients $d,e,f$ of  $F$ such that 
$$F(x(t),y(t)) \equiv  0$$
This is linear a system of 3 equations. Again we let [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/)([online calculator](http://maxima-online.org/?inc=r-959810951)) do the job

```
(%i9) F(x,y):=d*x+e*y+f
(%o9) F(x,y):=d*x+e*y+f
(%i10) x(t):=b_1*t+c_1
(%o10) x(t):=b_1*t+c_1
(%i11) y(t):=b_2*t+c_2
(%o11) y(t):=b_2*t+c_2
(%i12) solve(makelist(coeff(ratexpand(ev(F(x,y),x = x(t),y = y(t))),t,n) = 0,n,0,1),[d,e,f])
(%o12) [[d = -(%r10*b_2)/b_1,e = %r10,f = -(%r10*b_1*c_2-%r10*b_2*c_1)/b_1]]
(%i13) s:solve(append(makelist(coeff(ratexpand(ev(F(x,y),x = x(t),y = y(t))),t,n) = 0,n,0,1),[e = b_1]),[d,e,f])
(%o13) [[d = -b_2,e = b_1,f = b_2*c_1-b_1*c_2]]
(%i14) ratexpand(ev(F(x(t),y(t)),s))
(%o14) 0
```

and now we get

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
d &=& -b_2,\\
e &=& b_1,\\
f &=& b_2 c_1-b_1 c_2
\end{array}$$

If both $b_1=b_2=0$, too, then we have

$$\begin{array}{rcl}F(x,y)&=&c_2 x-c_1 y \\
x(t)&=&c_1 \\
y(t)&=&c_2
\end{array}$$

and if both $c_1=c_2=0$ we can set
$$F(x,y)=x^2+y^2$$

Answer (score 0):

If
$$x = a_1t^2+b_1t+c_1, \qquad y=a_2t^2+b_2t+c_2 \tag{1}$$

then we can get
$$a_2x-a_1y = (a_2b_1-a_1b_2) \,t + a_2c_1-a_1c_2 \tag{2}$$

If $a_2b_1 \ne a_1b_2$, we can use $(2)$ to eliminate $t$ from either of the equations in $(1)$, and also observe that the resulting equation is always (at the most) quadratic. Hence you have your real quadratic identity satisfied by all points on the curve.

Note that OTOH if $a_2b_1=a_1b_2$, equation $(2)$ by itself is a linear identity, representing a degenerate case, viz.  a line.

Comment: Is there some degeneracy assumption? What if $x(t) = 0, y(t) = t^2$, Then it seems to me the only $f$ that works is $f=0$?

Comment: @copper.hat In your e.g., the curve parametrised is a ray, the positive $y$-axis, and is a degenerate case. Perhaps  $f(x, y) = x = 0$ works, but that needs a condition $y \ge 0$.  Or $f(x, y) = y-kx^2 = 0$ works in the limit as $k\to \infty$.  Note this e.g. is included in the $a_2b_1 = a_1b_2$ degenerate case. I am not certain though that there are no other kinds of degeneracies (i.e. when $a_2b_1 \ne a_1b_2$.

Comment: Using your $f$, my example gives $f(x(t),y(t)) = t^2$ which is only zero at $t=0$.

Comment: I am guessing that with these sorts of problems that there are some standard implicit non-degeneracy assumptions.

Comment: @copper.hat True.  I suspect $a_2b_1 \ne a_1b_2$ is sufficient to avoid degeneracy.

Answer (score -3):

Consider the vector space of all real polynomials in $x$ and $y$ and degree less than or equal to $n$.The space is generated by $$S=(1,x,y,x^2,x y,y^2,...,x^n,x^{(n-1)} y,,,y^n)$$ and therefore it is finite dimensional and hence it has a finite basis.Then clearly the set $(S,x^{(n+1)})$ is linearly dependent and so the result follows.